# What is the M2DOC Eclipse Capella command to maximize an image in a Word page?

Tags: m2doc

What is the M2DOC Eclipse Capella command to maximize an image in a Word page?

I try this code:

```
{m:for rep | lc.representationByDescriptionName('Logical Architecture Blank')}
{m:if rep.getHeight() > rep.getWidth()}
{m:rep.asImage().setHeight(600)}
{m:else}
{m:rep.asImage().setWidth(400)}
{m:endif}
```

But give me this error:

```
{m:if rep.getHeight() >= rep.getWidth()} Invalid if statement: Couldn't find the 'getHeight(org.eclipse.sirius.viewpoint.DRepresentation)' serviceInvalid if statement: Couldn't find the 'getWidth(org.eclipse.sirius.viewpoint.DRepresentation)' serviceInvalid if statement: The predicate never evaluates to a boolean type ([]).
```

But I have insert all the sirius package uri.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the DRepresentation to call the service getHeight(), you should call it on the MImage:

```
rep.asImage().getHeight()
```

But for optimization, you can use a let:

```
{m:for rep | lc.representationByDescriptionName('Logical Architecture Blank')}
  {m:let image = rep.asImage()}
    {m:if image.getHeight() > image.getWidth()}
      {m:image.setHeight(600)}
    {m:else}
      {m:image.setWidth(400)}
    {m:endif}
  {m:endlet}
{m:endfor}
```